# make MySQL server has write permissions in the \xampp\tmp folder

Tags: mysql, sql, csv

how can i change the privilege of the directory \xampp\tmp in Mysql Server into write

coz when i want to create and write in a csv file with the query bellow , i'm facing this error msg in mysql (Can't create/write to file '\tmp\orders.csv' (Errcode: 2))

the query :

```
SELECT g.id, g.name, g.date, g.date_mod, g.status, cree_par, modifier_par
FROM glpi_tickets g , (select id, concat(realname , ' ' , firstname)
cree_par from glpi_users ) c, (select id, concat(realname , ' ' ,
firstname) modifier_par from glpi_users) m
where users_id_recipient <> users_id_lastupdater
and users_id_recipient = c.id
and users_id_lastupdater = m.id 
INTO OUTFILE '/tmp/orders.csv'
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
```

thanks in advance ^^

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Set writable permissions for /xampp/tmp (unix):

   ```
   sudo chmod 777 /xampp/tmp
   ```

   Windows:

   ```
   1. Right-click the file or folder, click Properties, and then click the Security tab.
   2. Click Advanced, and then click the Owner tab.
   3. Click Edit, and then do one of the following:
      · To change the owner to a user or group that is not listed, click Other users and groups and, in Enter the object name to select (examples), type the name of the user or group, and then click OK.
      · To change the owner to a user or group that is listed, in the Change owner to box, click the new owner.
   4. If you want to take ownership of the contents of the folder, select the Replace owner on sub containers and objects check box.
   5. Click OK, and then click Yes when you receive the following message:
       · You do not have permission to read the contents of directory folder name. Do you want to replace the directory permissions with permissions granting you Full Control?
       · All permissions will be replaced if you click Yes.
   Note folder name is the name of the folder that you want to take ownership of.
   6. Click OK, and then reapply the permissions and security settings that you want for the folder and its contents.
      Additional considerations
       · An administrator can take ownership of any file on the computer.
       · Assigning ownership of a file or a folder might require you to elevate your permissions using User Access Control.
   ```
2. Set right OUTFILE path

   ```
   SELECT g.id, g.name, g.date, g.date_mod, g.status, cree_par, modifier_par
   FROM glpi_tickets g , (select id, concat(realname , ' ' , firstname)
   cree_par from glpi_users ) c, (select id, concat(realname , ' ' ,
   firstname) modifier_par from glpi_users) m
   where users_id_recipient <> users_id_lastupdater
   and users_id_recipient = c.id
   and users_id_lastupdater = m.id 
   INTO OUTFILE '/xampp/tmp/orders.csv'
   FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
   ENCLOSED BY '"'
   LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
   ```

Comment: i'm working on windows 7 so where can i add the command (( sudo chmod 777 /xampp/tmp ))

Comment: the query will not overwrite the file if it already exists, instead showing this error message:

`#1086 - File 'xampp/tmp/order.csv'  already exists `
any solution ?

Comment: @YassineEdouiri For security reasons mysql can't overwrite existed file. So just remove file before creating table dump.

Comment: i'm working now in windows 7 , but i will use this code in unix using the cron i will execute this query every night , so please tell me if there is any code in unix can remove the file just before the cron execute the query