# session_set_save_handler - Failed to read session data: user

Tags: php, session

I receive:

> **Warning**:  session_start(): Failed to read session data: user
>   (path: C:\xampp\tmp) in **C:\xampp\htdocs\index.php** on line
>   **6**

When I try to use session_start.
I can't assign value to session and read it. any ideas?

```
<?php

GLOBAL $mysqli_link;

session_write_close();

function _open($save_path, $session_name) {
    return true;
}

function _close() {
    return true;
}

function _read($id) {
    GLOBAL $mysqli_link;

    //$id = hash('sha512', $id);

    $stmt = $mysqli_link->prepare("SELECT data FROM session WHERE  id = ? limit 1");
    $stmt->bind_param('s', $id);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result($data);
    $stmt->fetch();
    $stmt->close();

    if (isset($data)) {
        return $data;
    }
    else{
        return false;
    }
}

function _write($id, $dataw) {
    GLOBAL $mysqli_link;

    //$id = hash('sha512', $id);

    $access = date ("ymdHis");

    if($dataw!=""){
        $stmt = $mysqli_link->prepare("REPLACE INTO session VALUES (?,?,?)");
        $stmt->bind_param('sss', $id, $access, $dataw);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->close();
    }

    return true;
}

function _destroy($id) {
    GLOBAL $mysqli_link;

    //$id = hash('sha512', $id);

    $stmt = $mysqli_link->prepare("DELETE FROM session WHERE id = ?");
    $stmt->bind_param('s', $id);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->close();
}

function _clean($max) {
    GLOBAL $mysqli_link;
    $access = date ("YmdHis");

    $stmt = $mysqli_link->prepare("DELETE FROM session WHERE access < DATE_SUB('$access', INTERVAL 3 hour)");
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->close();

    return true;
}

session_set_save_handler('_open','_close','_read','_write','_destroy','_clean');
register_shutdown_function('session_write_close');

?>
```

maybe something wrong in my function?

Comment: ... looked in `C:\xampp\tmp`?

Comment: Assuming windows? Look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16681127/make-mysql-server-has-write-permissions-in-the-xampp-tmp-folder). Probably permissions. Not sure who apache runs as for you...